# Parsing a dynamic Json object in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a json of the following format :

```
 {
    httpGroup1: {
    httpmember1: {
            key1: {
                prop1: propvalue1
                prop2: propvalue2
                prop3: propvalue3
            }
            key2: keyvalue2
            key3: {
                prop4: propvalue4
            }
        }
        httpmember2: {
            key1: {
                prop1: propvalue1
                prop2: propvalue2
                prop3: propvalue3
            }
            key2: keyvalue2
            key3: {
                prop4: propvalue4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where group is a json object consisting of dynamic keys and it can have any number of members as values (which is again a dynamic json object).  How do i parse such json and pass it to the view so that it can be displayed on an html page? 
I will receive the array of these json objects from the server.

Comment: This is exactly why you have json arrays. can you restructure your object so that it becomes `httpmembers : [{ //member1}, {//member2}, etc]` ?

Comment: Since i am getting this json object from another application , i have no control over, i can't restructure it.

Comment: If you can't change the format of that, then you're going to have a really hard time parsing it. Apart from it not utilizing JSON arrays, it's not even valid JSON.

Comment: If you don't have any control on the structure the only thing you can do is parse property by property. What are you using to parse this JSON object?

Comment: i am using Gson Parser

Comment: This is not json